# Android Studio Canary 4 puts red line under any method from class AppCompatActivity although it compiles

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have update Android Studio to the new Canary version (canary 4), and it puts a red line under any method from AppCompatActivity since all my activities extends that class although it compiles and runs very good but i need to get rid of these red lines that are meaningless.

Comment: does it error? or gradle sync error?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by putting google() inside "repositories" like below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() <---
        jcenter()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart. See if it works, it did for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me, still getting the red lines